# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, decode

I know there are a lot of questions regarding the encoding-decoding but I seem not to figure this out:

```
def content(title, sents):
sent_elems = []
for sent_i, sent in enumerate(sents, 1):


    elem = u"<a name=\"{i}\">[{i}]</a> <a href=\"#{i}\" id={i}>{text}</a>".format(i=sent_i, text=sent.text)
    sent_elems.append(elem)
doc = u"""<html>
<head>
<title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>{elems}</body>
</html>""".format(title=title, elems="\n".join(sent_elems))

return doc
```

Calling the content function will give me this error on a very rare cases (maybe one-two times in my whole dataset):

```
 File "processing.py", line 68, in score_summary
self._write_config(references, summary)
  File "processing.py", line 56, in _write_config
reference_files = self._write_references(references, reference_dir)
  File "processing.py", line 44, in _write_references
f.write(rouge_summary_content(reference.id, reference.sents))
  File "processing.py", line 154, in rouge_summary_content
</html>""".format(title=title, elems="\n".join(sent_elems))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I've change to:

```
sent_elems.append(elem.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
```

and also

```
sent_elems.append(elem.decode("utf-8", "replace"))
```

Still the same error.

I had a look at the data and couldn't figure out why this happens. I checked for the file that this error happens and still no non-utf8 char.

I also added this in my file:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

The problem still is there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do **not** use `sys.setdefaultencoding()`. That's akin to binding up a broken leg and walking on instead of going to the ER to have it set in a cast. Stuff is still broken, you'll get to feel the pain later and will have to reset the bone.

Comment: It is most likely your `title` that is bytes, not unicode.

Comment: That will create more problems even. by setting sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") I've skipped almost all of my encoding-decoding error. There are few persistent cases that I need to rather get rid of or know where is the source of them.

Comment: No, it means you are now ignoring the fact you are mixing byte strings and unicode values rather than properly decoding all incoming data to Unicode as soon as possible. Fix those errors instead.

Comment: Other modules **count on the default being ASCII**. You now are violating invariant.

Comment: I think now that it's my title. I give the title chr(65+index) and when my index will go over 25 then the char() might give a code which is not utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

My titles are as `chr(65+index)`, so when it goes over all capital letter it will print some non utf-8 chars. I changed it to `str(index)` and it solved my original problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem was not solved by that. I've got another error.

Answer (score 0):

**if your data looks like the one given below:**

> **data**="0\x80\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x07\x04\xa0\x800\x80\x02\x01\x01\x0e0\x0c\x06\b*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x02\x05\x05....."

**By following the below method , we can decode it in utf8**

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
decoded = urllib.unquote(encoded).decode('utf8')
```

The result would be like this:

```
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAq...
```